# PhpStorm-EAP: Syncing files with remote server

Tags: phpstorm

When saving files (Ctrl-S), it's being uploaded automatically (as set in the config) and overwriting possible changes. Can I set PhpStorm to check and ask confirmation before overwriting ?

When I use the 'Synchronize myfile' option, it says 'Synchronized myfile completed successfullly', but I can't see any change on the server. I don't really understand what it's doing.

Comment: _When I use the 'Synchronize myfile' option, it says 'Synchronized myfile completed successfullly', but I can't see any change on the server_
What folder do you invoke it against? Please try to use the project root. Still no changes?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I set PhpStorm to check and ask confirmation before overwriting ?

You can, just enable "Warn when uploading over a newer file" and "Notify about remote changes" in "Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment | Options".

[image]